# Google Analytics pushing worng value in 'checkout' actionField option

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-datalayer

There is common JSPF var dataLayer = window.dataLayer = dataLayer || []; has declared.

**On Checkout step** -3

```
dataLayer.push({
            'event' : 'checkout',
            'ecommerce' : {
                'currencyCode' : 'GBP',
                'checkout' : {
                    'actionField' : {
                        'step' : 3,
                        'option' : '<some-value>',
                        'tax' : '<some-value>',
                        **'action' : 'checkout'**
                    },
                    'products' : '<some-value>'
                }
            }
        });
```

It is working fine. Pushing correct data.

**On Checkout step - 4**

```
dataLayer.push({
            'event' : 'checkout',
            'ecommerce' : {
                'currencyCode' : 'GBP',
                'checkout' : {
                    'actionField' : {
                        'step' : 4,
                        'option' : '<some-value>',
                        'tax' : '<some-value>',
                        **'action' : 'purchase'**
                    },
                    'products' : '<some-value>'
                }
            }
        });
```

It still pushing 'checkout' not 'purchase'. The datalayer pushing of elements from same file for step-3 and step-4. And declaration is from .JSPf which is included in it. It seems like 'action' element is cached.I had tried with cleaning browser history but no success.

Please tell where i had lacked.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `actionField.action` field is automatically populated by GTM/Universal Analytics. You should never manually add a value to it.

The field value is derived from the property name that wraps `actionField` and `products`. Thus if the hit is a "Checkout" hit, the property key would be `checkout`, and if the hit is a "Purchase" hit, the property key would be `purchase`.

Example Checkout hit for step 4:

```
event: 'checkout',
ecommerce: {
  checkout: {
    actionField: {
      step: 4,
      option: 'some-option'
    }
  }
}
```

Example Purchase hit:

```
event: 'purchase',
ecommerce: {
  currencyCode: 'GBP',
  purchase: {
    actionField: {
      id: 'some-transaction-id',
      revenue: 'some-transaction-revenue',
      tax: 'some-transaction-tax',
      shipping: 'some-transaction-shipping'
    },
    products: [{
      ...products in the purchase...
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Simo. On my local environment it works fine. It created problem only for higher environment. Whats the reason for this?

Comment: Can you please suggest link where i can confirm automatically populated field names like 'actionField.action'.

Comment: This has not been documented. It's easy to verify by doing 
`dataLayer.push({event: 'checkout', ecommerce: { checkout: { actionField: { step: 1 }}}})` in the JavaScript console on a page where the Custom Event `checkout` fires an Enhanced Ecommerce enabled tag. When you open the `dataLayer` after this command, you'll find the `actionField.action` field automatically added to the payload, even though you didn't push it. The dev guide for GTM+Enhanced Ecommerce ([link](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce)) has all the details you need to build the `dataLayer` objects.

Comment: That is 3 hours of my life I will never get back... Thank you so much for posting this. I was going mental trying to work out where the action was coming from in my code.